# Is the 1" rule completely or only partially ignored on a successful charge in Necromunda N18?

Tags: necromunda

When my fighter does a Charge (Double) action, is he allowed to move into the 1" space of any fighters he passes or is he only allowed to move into the 1" space of those fighters he intends to end up being in base-to-base contact with?

I am talking about the latest edition of Necromunda, started through [Necromunda Rulebook](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/281782/necromunda-rulebook) in 2018, sometimes referred to as N18.

Page 58 of the Necromunda Rulebook in section "Charge (Double)" states the following:

> A charging fighter can move to within 1" of one or more enemy fighters
> … but if they do move to within 1" they must have sufficient movement
> to get into base to base contact with at least one enemy fighter …

And page 61 in section "The 1" rule" states also:

> The only exception to this rule is when … makes a Charge (Double)
> action, in which case they may move within 1" of one or more enemy
> fighters, provided that they end their movement in base to base
> contact with one or more enemy fighters

For comparison, in the predecessor edition N17's rulebook, Necromunda: Underhive page 46 the following is written:

> … they can move within 1" of a standing or Pinned enemy (or more than
> one if they wish) but if they do, they must move into base contact,
> becoming Engaged.

Which seems less complex and easier to grasp at first. Especially because the "base-to-base with at least one" condition is missing here.

I tend to believe that the "one or more" fighters that one can come closer than 1" to should be the same as those the fighter intends to come to base-to-base contact with. Together with the rule that a charge should always use the shortest path possible, this would allow fighters to protect fighters from being charged by blocking tight corridors or at least make it a lot harder to charge someone by increasing the distance to be moved around them.

I believe this mostly because in other Games Workshop games like Kill Team (second edition) which shares a lot of similarities to N18 and was released in the same year, it is even explicitly stated ([Kill Team Core Manual](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameexpansion/262067/warhammer-40000-kill-team-core-manual) page 24):

> It cannot move within 1" of an enemy model that was not a target of
> its charge.

I think this is supposed to simulate that if a fighter moves along an enemy fighter too close they might interfere with their charge.

This also appears in much simpler games of Games Workshop like Warhammer Quest: Blackstone Fortress, where a characters movement ends as soon as it comes into adjacency to a hostile model.

Is there any official source that make interpretation more clear? What would be your interpretation and why?

Comment: Not an answer, but I read the newer rule as less ambiguously allowing you to be within 1" of other models and not in base contact, so long as you reach the charge target